# ListView model reload with U1db.Query

Tags: ubuntu-touch, qml, database, qt5

I have a ListView with his model coming from a U1db.Query
The reading and saving operation form U1db works, but i need to update the ListView model when a new item is inserted in the database, to diplay the last content retrieved with the query. I have also tried with ListView`and`UbuntuListView` but i can't solve this issue.
I cant 'pull' the List to refresh it but i get error like:

```
`Property 'update' of object U1db::Query(0xe097e0) is not a function`
```

I have looked at the sdk doc but i haven't found any useful examples.
Thanks for any suggestions !

Here the snippet (i have omitted some detils):

```
 //delegate component for the listView
Component {
            id: peopleListDelegate

            Item {
                id: personItem                

                //draw a rectangle aroun the content to display 
                Rectangle {
                 //content omitted 
                }

                // This mouse region covers the entire delegate
                MouseArea {
                   //content omitted              
                }

                Row {
                    id: topLayout                    
                    //display some content to be shown inside the Rectangle
                 }
            }
        }




//the listView that show DB Query result
    ListView  {
                     id: listView
                     anchors.fill: parent
                     model : allPeopleQuery
                     delegate: peopleListDelegate

                     highlight: highlightComponent                 
                     focus: true

                     Component{
                         id: listHeader

                         Item {
                             width: parent.width
                             height: units.gu(10)

                             Text{
                                 anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
                                 anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
                                 text: i18n.tr("<b> Total people found: </b>") + listView.count
                             }
                         }
                     }

                     header: listHeader

                     PullToRefresh  {                            
                             refreshing: listView.model.status === ListModel.Loading
                             onRefresh: listView.model.update()  // HERE THE PROBLEM, (also using reload() doesn't work)
                         }
                 }

    U1db.Database {
            id: mypeopleDb
           .....
        }

       U1db.Index{
           database: mypeopleDb
           id: all_field_index
           expression: .......
       }


      U1db.Query {
           id: allPeopleQuery
           index: all_field_index
           query: ["*", "*"]
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

After some days of attempts i have found how to "fix" this.
A ListView with a query fom U1db as "model" have a builtin automatic refresh of the model (eg: if you add/remove items in the DB and the resultSet of the query changes the model will be updated).
But, using the code above inside an AdaptiveLayout, and switching
between pages with statement like:

```
myAdaptiveLayout.addPageToNextColumn(aPage,Qt.resolvedUrl('AddPerson.qml'))
```

the automatic refresh of the model doesn't work !

If you include the page code from the file 'AddPerson.qml' inside the same qml file where is defined the AdaptiveLayout the ListView model auto refresh works !!!

**NOTE**: I don't know if this solution is a workaround or is a qml bug.